# Php delete request error

Tags: php, mysql

I've a problem to delete in my table mySQL and I don't understand why.
If you can help me.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include ('config.php');

// Recup the $_POST
$idTournament ='2';

// querys all the participation before to delete the tournament
$request1 = $handler->prepare('DELETE FROM Participate WHERE tournament_id = :idTournament')

//bind the parameters
$request1->bindParam(':idTournament', $idTournament, PDO::PARAM_INT);

//execute the prepared statement
$request1->execute();

?>
```

However, when I put my console the line "DELETE from ...", it works. So...

Thank you

Mickey74

Comment: Do you receive any errors? What's the state of $request1 after execute?

Comment: Try with $request1 = $handler->prepare('DELETE FROM Participate WHERE tournament_id = '.$idTournament);

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot to put semicolon after **prepare** statement.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include ('config.php');

// Recup the $_POST
$idTournament ='2';

// querys all the participation before to delete the tournament
$request1 = $handler->prepare('DELETE FROM Participate WHERE tournament_id = :idTournament');

//bind the parameters
$request1->bindParam(':idTournament', $idTournament, PDO::PARAM_INT);

//execute the prepared statement
$request1->execute();

?>
```